# Two player game with marbles using optimal strategies

Tags: logic, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

Consider the two-player game that consists of a single bowl of $n$ marbles. The players alternate turns. During each turn, a player can remove $2^k$ marbles, for any $k \ge 0$ of his or her choice. The winner is the person who removes the last marble. Determine all $n \ge 0$ for which the first player wins, supposing both players use optimal strategies.

Here is what I have done so far: n=1 is a winner. n=5 is a winner.

This is a problem I am doing for fun, it would not harm me to show me the answer and work

Comment: What about $n=2,3,4,6,7,8,9$? If you work out all of those correctly, you should see a very simple pattern.

Comment: Don't forget when $n$ is a power of $2$, player one can just win on the first turn.

Comment: Can you explain why you think "n=5 is a winner"?

Comment: @BobKrueger n=5  is a winner since you can take 2 leaving your opponent with 3 which is a loser. Can you use the answer space below to show full solution?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott 1,4,5,7,8 are all winners I believe

Comment: @JLinsta Yes I see, do you know of any advanced theorems or equations that can solve this question quickly?

Comment: I was told by a StackExchange warning and also other people to not have extended discussions in the comments. If any of you are able to provide a solution and work below please do that and I will ask if I have any questions about any steps that you have done.

Comment: @Identiconn: Yes, that is correct. $2$ is also a winning position, since you can take both marbles. $3,6$, and $9$, however, are losing positions: you can easily check that no matter what you do, you will leave your opponent a winning position. That suggests a conjecture…

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I currently have 1,2,4,5,7,8 as winners. I can't see a conjecture. They are a mix of odd and even numbers. There is nothing I can add or multiply to get the list. Is there an advanced theorem or equation I can use to quickly solve this problem?

Comment: I now see that it goes 12 45 78 1011 1314 1617 and that the losers are multiples of 3. But how is that said mathematically to translate into this word problem?

Comment: @Identiconn: There is not. But now that you’ve identified the multiples of $3$ as the losing positions, I’ll write up an answer outlining how one proves such a conjecture.

Comment: Are you the same user who asked [the same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4047910/362967) previously? You seem to be parroting the same comments and still do very little work yourself.

Comment: Please stop posting the same questions over and over again using multiple user names, it is an abuse of the site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this user has posted the same questions multiple times, and has refused to show even minimal effort on any of them.

Answer (score 2):

You’ve discovered that the multiples of $3$ appear to be the losing positions, the other non-negative integers being the winning positions. There is a standard way to prove this kind of result (when it’s true!).

Let $W$ be the set of winning positions, and let $L$ be the set of losing positions. As you may have realized in analyzing the smaller positions, a winning position is one from which you can put your opponent in a losing position, and a losing position is one from which every legal move leaves your opponent in a winning position. In the case of this game that means:

- if $n\in W$, then there is some $k\ge 0$ such that $n-2^k\in L$, and
- if $n\in L$, then for every $k\ge 0$ either $2^k>n$, or $n-2^k\in W$.

In fact, the cases

$$n-2^k\in L\text{ for some }k\ge 0$$

and

$$\text{for each }k\ge 0\text{ either }2^k>n,\text{ or }n-2^k\in W$$

are mutually exclusive, so we can go further:

- $n\in W$ if and only if there is some $k\ge 0$ such that $n-2^k\in L$, and
- $n\in L$ if and only if for every $k\ge 0$ either $2^k>n$, or $n-2^k\in W$.

You’ve conjectured that $L=\{3n:n\ge 0\}$, and $W=\Bbb N\setminus L$. You can prove this by showing that two bulleted statements above are true for this choice of $W$ and $L$.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the detailed work! After viewing it for a couple minutes I believe that I understand, but I have one question. To clarify, writing down both bulleted statements would solve the question "Determine all $n \ge 0$ for which the first player wins, supposing both players use optimal strategies." ?

Comment: @Identiconn: Yes, if you can prove that those statements hold for the $W$ and $L$ that I defined, then you’ve proved that the losing positions are precisely the multiples of $3$ and the winning positions all of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and think about this problem inductively. Note that every single position is either a winning position or a losing position assuming both players play the optimal strategy. Furthermore, a position is winning if and only if you can put your opponent in a losing position by taking out $2^k$ marbles for some $k \geq 0$. Using this idea:

1 is winning because player one can simply take all the marbles

2 is winning for the same reason

3 is losing because player one can only put player two in a winning position

4 is winning

5 is winning because player one can take 2 marbles and put player two in a losing position (3)

Now we can continue this process for each $n$: $n$ is winning if and only if $n$ is a power of 2 or $n$ is $2^k$ more than one of the previous losing positions for some $k \geq 0$.

(Though this idea is assuming every position is either winning or losing, which probably requires more thought.)

Comment: As there are no ties, you can divide all the positions into $P$ positions and $N$ positions, where $P$ positions are wins for the previous player and $N$ positions are wins for the next player.  This is just what you were alluding to.  A $P$ position is one that can only move to $N$ positions.  An $N$ position is one that can move to a $P$ position.  You can then induct upward in the chain of positions.

Comment: Ross Millikan and JLinsta, can you please view the other answer and verify it? I believe that it is correct but it would be reassuring to see other people verify it.